# Custom Background default color not changing

Tags: custom-background

I need to set several default states for a theme's background. The idea is that the background changes upon choosing a color scheme. Everything is working and changing EXCEPT the background color. The color only changes if saved from the admin screen. Am I missing something?

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_custom_background');

function theme_custom_background(){
  $theme = genesis_get_option('bf_style_selection');

  switch ($theme) {
    case 'bf-blue':
      $bg_color = 'def1fc';
      $bg_image = 'header-bg-blue.gif';
      break;
    case 'bf-black':
      $bg_color = 'dadada';
      $bg_image = 'header-bg-black.gif';
      break;
  }

  $defaults = array(
    'default-image'          => get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/images/'.$bg_image,
    'default-color'          => $bg_color,
    'default-repeat'         => 'repeat-x',
    'default-position-x'     => 'top',
    'wp-head-callback'       => '_custom_background_cb',
    'admin-head-callback'    => '',
    'admin-preview-callback' => ''
  );

  add_theme_support( 'custom-background', $defaults);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have hunted down the problem. It is the `_custom_background_cb` function in `wp-includes/theme.php` file. on line 1272 the comment "A default has to be specified in style.css. It will not be printed here."

Line 1272 is where the color is being retrieved:

```
$color = get_theme_mod( 'background_color' );
```

If we change that to:

```
$color = get_theme_mod( 'background_color', get_theme_support( 'custom-background', 'default-color' ) );
```

We can get a default color without the need to have it saved in `theme_mod`. We can still override the color with a saved value.

So, I duplicated the callback into my own function and this is what is working:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_custom_background');

function theme_custom_background(){
  $theme = genesis_get_option('bf_style_selection');

  switch ($theme) {
    case 'bf-blue':
      $bg_color = 'def1fc';
      $bg_image = 'header-bg-blue.gif';
      break;
    case 'bf-black':
      $bg_color = 'dadada';
      $bg_image = 'header-bg-black.gif';
      break;
  }

  $defaults = array(
    'default-image'          => get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/images/'.$bg_image,
    'default-color'          => $bg_color,
    'default-repeat'         => 'repeat-x',
    'default-position-x'     => 'top',
    'wp-head-callback'       => '_bf_custom_background_cb',
    'admin-head-callback'    => '',
    'admin-preview-callback' => ''
  );

  add_theme_support( 'custom-background', $defaults);
}

function _bf_custom_background_cb() {
  // $background is the saved custom image, or the default image.
  $background = set_url_scheme( get_background_image() );

  // $color is the saved custom color.
  // Added second parameter to get_theme_mod() to get_theme_support() as we need default colors to show with needing to save.
  $color = get_theme_mod( 'background_color', get_theme_support( 'custom-background', 'default-color' ) );

  if ( ! $background && ! $color )
    return;

  $style = $color ? "background-color: #$color;" : '';

  if ( $background ) {
    $image = " background-image: url('$background');";

    $repeat = get_theme_mod( 'background_repeat', get_theme_support( 'custom-background', 'default-repeat' ) );
    if ( ! in_array( $repeat, array( 'no-repeat', 'repeat-x', 'repeat-y', 'repeat' ) ) )
      $repeat = 'repeat';
    $repeat = " background-repeat: $repeat;";

    $position = get_theme_mod( 'background_position_x', get_theme_support( 'custom-background', 'default-position-x' ) );
    if ( ! in_array( $position, array( 'center', 'right', 'left' ) ) )
      $position = 'left';
    $position = " background-position: top $position;";

    $attachment = get_theme_mod( 'background_attachment', get_theme_support( 'custom-background', 'default-attachment' ) );
    if ( ! in_array( $attachment, array( 'fixed', 'scroll' ) ) )
      $attachment = 'scroll';
    $attachment = " background-attachment: $attachment;";

    $style .= $image . $repeat . $position . $attachment;
  }
?>
<style type="text/css" id="custom-background-css">
body.custom-background { <?php echo trim( $style ); ?> }
</style>
<?php
}
```